# iron-selector selected={{}} binding with iron-pages selected={{}} (Switcheroo)

Tags: polymer-1.0

So i made a custom-menu with iron-selector and put it inside on another custom element wich contains iron-pages and i can't bind the buttons of my menu with the content of the pages.
Basically a Switcheroo with custom elements.
Here is some code (simplified):

my-menu

```
<dom-module id="my-menu">
  <style>
    :host {display: inline-block;        }
  </style>    
  <template>
    <iron-selector id="menu" selected="{{menuSelected}}" attr-for-selected="name-menu">
      <div name-menu="portfolio" class="button"></div>
      <div name-menu="about" class="button"></div>
      <div name-menu="contact" class="button"></div>
    </iron-selector>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-menu',
      behaviors: [Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior],
      poperties:{
        menuSelected:{
          type: String,
          value: 'portfolio'
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

and my-pages

```
<dom-module id="my-pages">
  <style>
    :host {display: inline-block;}
  </style>

  <template>

    <my-menu menu-selected="{{pageSelected}}"></my-menu>

    <iron-pages attr-for-selected="page" selected="{{pageSelected}}"> 
      <section page="portfolio"> Some Content </section>
      <section page="about"> Some Content </section>
      <section page="contact"> Some Content </section>
    </iron-pages>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-pages',
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Thanks for reading this! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 'notify: true' to menuSelected. So that my-pages knows when my-menu modifies the value of menuSelected. Also as others mentioned, you need to fix the spelling of properties. Change it as below:

```
  properties:{
    menuSelected:{
      type: String,
      notify: true,
      value: 'portfolio'
    }
  }
```

Comment: ok! Yay!!!! the typo error already has been corrected, but the notify: true is the solution. thanks a lot. 
So, always you want to bind atributtes as a porperty and publish, you should tell that will change with notify?

Comment: You need to set 'notify: true' if the child element is going to change the value and the parent needs to know it. It is not required if the child element is just going to listen and consume the updates to the parent property.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the `Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior` behaviour because it is a dependency loaded by `iron-selector` already.

You've also spelt `properties` incorrectly in the `my-menu` element: 'poperties'...

Comment: Thanks! i hate when you spent the day debuging and its a typo error but unfortunately still missing something here