# How to properly bind iron-selector to iron-pages?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to do the same basic task as this other question, [iron-selector selected={{}} binding with iron-pages selected={{}}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673783/iron-selector-selected-binding-with-iron-pages-selected-switcheroo), but I believe my case must be different, since I cannot replicate the solution.

I want to have a menu of buttons with `iron-selector`, and when clicked, the content with `iron-pages`should change.

So I have the actual page `about.htm` that has 1 webcomponent for the button-menu, called `about-buttons.htm` and then 1 webcomponent for each page, that should load according to which button is pushed by the user; `about-who.htm`, `about-manifesto` and `about-team`.

**My question is**:

How can I with this structure of my web components bind my buttons with my pages - and / or why is my current method wrong?

There's a lot of different ways to do a simple data binding like this. My method here is definitely not simple, and it does not work (by clicking buttons, the pages does not change).

---

So my `about.htm` looks like this (and this is the page people will visit):

```
    <about-buttons selected="{{who}}">
    </about-buttons>

    <about-iron-pages attr-for-selected="name" selected="{{who}}" fallback-selection="who">   
        <about-us name="who">
        </about-us> 
        <about-manifesto name="manifesto">
        </about-manifesto>
        <about-team name="team">
        </about-team>    
    </about-iron-pages>
```

My `about-buttons.htm` looks like this:

```
            <iron-selector 
                attr-for-selected="name" 
                selected="{{buttonSelected}}" 
                fallback-selection="who" 
                class="f-column f-column_3 f-column_mobile_2">
                <button class="f-button-group__button" name="manifesto">Manifesto</button>
                <button class="f-button-group__button" name="who">Who we are</button>
                <button class="f-button-group__button" name="team">Team</button>
            </iron-selector>
```

With this script:

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'about-buttons',
    properties: {
        buttonSelected: {
            type: String,
            notify: true,
            value: 'who'
        }
    }
  });
</script>
```

And here's my version of `iron-pages`:

```
<dom-module id="about-iron-pages">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host {
                display: block;
            }
            :host > ::content > :not(.iron-selected) {
                display: none !important;
            }
        </style>
        <content>
        </content>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
          is: 'about-iron-pages',
          behaviors: [
            Polymer.IronResizableBehavior,
            Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior
          ],

          properties: {
            activateEvent: {
              type: String,
              value: null,
            }
          },
          observers: [
            '_selectedPageChanged(selected)'
          ],
          _selectedPageChanged: function(selected, old) {
            this.async(this.notifyResize);
          }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Your code seems to have some errors: `buttonSelected` and `selected` property names are inconsistent. Also, simply clicking the buttons in `<about-buttons>` doesn't automatically select on `<iron-selector>`. Finally it seem's your missing the `<iron-pages>` element entirely in the `<about-iron-pages>`'s template :)

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, your attribute in `<about-buttons selected="...">` does not match the actual property name. For `<about-buttons>.buttonSelected`, your attribute should be `button-selected`, and that's the only change to your code needed to get the selector working ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WJwYVAoHjVLrTvxAoeNQ?p=preview)):

```
<about-buttons button-selected="{{who}}" ...>
```

Perhaps there's more context to your need for `<about-buttons>` and `<about-iron-pages>`, but otherwise, if you're only trying to implement a tabbed view, you could just use Polymer's components.
Specifically, `<about-buttons>` could be replaced by [`<paper-tabs>`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tabs) and `<about-iron-pages>` by [`<iron-pages>`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-pages) ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2oO1idwcJ3hjzIUbjqu9?p=preview)).

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!